# Can a user vote for a self-edited posts?

Tags: discussion, voting, edits

Can a user edit and then *vote* on a post originated from another user?

Comment: Do you mean up/downvotes or accept/decline votes for the edit?  The former can, the later can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, user can vote for self-edited posts, but points belonging to the post go to the original owner.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

Comment: Then who earns the points to edited post...

Comment: @ACoder Well, the original poster, obviously. If you have a very substantive improvement in mind, content-wise, consider posting your own answer instead of editing an existing one.

Comment: @lunboks he [can't](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1208920/sachin-mhetre) for six more days. :)

Answer (score 3):

As you edited a post created from somebody else, you are allowed to vote it. You cannot vote your own posts, but editing somebody else's post doesn't make the post yours.
Even in the case of CW posts, any badge that is gained because the score of those posts is given to the user who created the post, not to the user who wrote the most of the post.

Comment: Clarification: by OP, you mean the "original poster" of the _answer_, right? 'Cos usually it's used to refer to the askr.

Comment: What I reported is valid for both answers, and questions; that is why I said _posts_. With OP I mean the original poster, who created the post.

Comment: Yep, that's what I thought.. Just got a bit confused out there :)